# Dart Vs JavaScript loading time comparison

Tags: javascript, compare, dart, page-load-time, load-time

I've created 2 versions of a Google Maps application - one with Dart and one with JavaScript code compiled from the original Dart code. I run both of these locally on my computer not on the public internet and I am looking for a way to record the loading speed of each to compare them is there a way of doing this or service/program that does this?

Comment: The Chrome dev tools Timeline functionality isn't what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks that's done it

Comment: Can you share your results with us, please?

Comment: Yeah as soon as I've completed them I will put the results up here

Comment: RIP Joe Programmer: Died waiting for OP to deliver

Answer (score 2):

Chrome has a decent profile in the dev tools that can give you fine-grain timings like this:

[image: Chrome profiling]

There's an article on how to use this on the [Chrome developer site, here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling).